# QtRuby InputDialog with default text

Tags: ruby, qt, qtruby

With QtRuby, is it possible to create an input dialog that already has a value in the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the initial value as the 5th parameter of [QInputDialog::getText](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qinputdialog.html#getText) method.

Comment: Thanks. I just started looking through the examples like I should've done to begin with.